# Jquery if/else conflict with code beneath

Tags: jquery

How to overcome the if else is not overwritten by code beneath?

When you select Apartment and in if is to show `<div class="apartment-options">` and `<div class="general-opion-two">` but this get overwritten by the else for the house if/else.

```js
$('.apartment-options, .garage-options, .house-options, .general-opion-one, .general-opion-two').slideUp();


$('.wrapper').on('change', function() {
  let current_selection = $(".select-option option:selected").val();

  if (current_selection == '398') {
    $('.apartment-options, .general-opion-two').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.apartment-options, .general-opion-two').slideUp();
  }

  if (current_selection == '413') {
    $('.garage-options, .general-opion-one').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.garage-options, .general-opion-one').slideUp();
  }

  if (current_selection == '418') {
    $('.house-options, .general-opion-two').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.house-options, .general-opion-two').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="select-option" name="property_type[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="398">Apartment</option>
    <option value="413">Garage</option>
    <option value="418">House</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="apartment-options">
  <p>This is my apartment option</p>
</div>
<div class="garage-options">
  This is my garage option
</div>
<div class="house-options">
  This is my house option
</div>

<div class="general-opion-one">
  This option should show on the House and Garage
</div>
<div class="general-opion-two">
  This option should show on the House and Apartment
</div>
```

And here is working pen: https://codepen.io/danijel112/pen/MWKPLMX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't to do with the `if` conditions themselves, but instead because your logic affects the same element in two different ways based on a single selection.

For example, when you choose `apartment` `.general-opion-two` is shown. Then in the `.house` condition hides it again as that option was not selected.

To fix this separate the display logic for each element in the DOM in to its own condition.

Also note that to hide elements on load you should use CSS, not JS, as the latter will lead to a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

```js
$('.select-option').on('change', function() {
  let current_selection = $(".select-option").val();
  let getSlideMethod = (b) => b ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
  
  $('.apartment-options')[getSlideMethod(current_selection === '398')]();
  $('.garage-options')[getSlideMethod(current_selection === '413')]();
  $('.house-options')[getSlideMethod(current_selection === '418')]();

  $('.general-opion-one')[getSlideMethod(current_selection === '413')]();
  $('.general-opion-two')[getSlideMethod(current_selection === '398' || current_selection === '418')](); 
});
```

```css
.apartment-options,
.garage-options,
.house-options,
.general-opion-one,
.general-opion-two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="select-option" name="property_type[]">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="398">Apartment</option>
    <option value="413">Garage</option>
    <option value="418">House</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="apartment-options">
  <p>This is my apartment option</p>
</div>
<div class="garage-options">
  This is my garage option
</div>
<div class="house-options">
  This is my house option
</div>

<div class="general-opion-one">
  This option should show on the House and Garage
</div>
<div class="general-opion-two">
  This option should show on the House and Apartment
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for. I couldn't figure out how overcome if/else because its definition is fixed. It must be value='xx' and it must target this class. All i was currently be able to think of is if/else or switch statement. But this helps a lot. And for the css to hide elements at start i do that in my app but this was faster for the demo, yes NEVER hide div on load with javascript.